# R File Size (memory) limit: Discrepancy across OSX/Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, remote-server

Hardware:

1. MacBook Air 2013, 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, 1,3 GHz Intel Core i5. Yosemite 10.10.5.
2. Remote Cloud Server, 6 GB RAM, 2 CPUs. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / RStudio Server.

I have a large dataset (32,500,000 x 88) that I managed to compile from .csv to .RDS in RStudio on my 5-year old MacBook air. Considering that the laptop lacks the hardware to handle predictive modelling on the dataset, I uploaded the database .RDS of 2.6GB to my Cloud Server.

My problem: 
When I attempt to *readRDS()* the database on my remote Ubuntu stack through either the RStudio Server or ssh/terminal R, I receive the notorious *Error: cannot allocate vector of size 123.9 Mb* error. The same situation occurs for a .fst version of the db in combination with *read.fst()*.

What I fail to understand is, **how does the remote server fail to even load the dataset when my laptop can do it in 3-4 minutes?**

MacBook Air SessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Remote Server sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

MacBook Air Ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
Jacobs-MacBook-Air:~ JacobGrapendal$
```

Remote Server Ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 23796
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 23796
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Object size of loaded .RDS on my laptop:

```
object.size(core)
20021819880 bytes
```

Hence, the remote server is running 64-bit R and has uncapped virtual memory usage. Still, it cannot do what my 5-year old MacBook Air can do. Why?